# Avoiding duplicating CSS styles?

Tags: css

I am using Html and JQuery. I have below CSS styles in my styles.css.

```
#someTable{
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:80%;
    height:98px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color:mintcream;
}
```

and

```
#anotherTable{
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:80%;
    height:98px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

In above css styles, all the styles are same except `background-color` remaining all are duplicated. How can avoid duplicates and extend the properties of `firstTable` ?

Comment: Combine all the common properties into a `class`, then create 2 more classes for the `background-color` override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them together, and redefine the exceptions:

```
#someTable, #anotherTable{
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:80%;
    height:98px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color:mintcream;
}

#anotherTable{
    background-color:white; /* Set the exception */
}
```

I'm assuming you can't style `table`. You can remove the background-color from the group, and make it an own set, like `#anotherTable`, but this will save you 4 lines :)

You could give both tables a class, and use that as the 'group' selector, but ID's are way faster than classes. In this case, **IMO**, you should stick with the ID's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use classes. It would look like this :

**CSS:**

```
.masterclass{ here you put all the properties that are the same } 

#table1 { here the specific details , your color in this case }
#table2 { here the specific details , your color in this case }
```

**html :**

```
<table class='masterclass' id='table1'> </table>
<table class='masterclass' id='table2'> </table>
```

Comment: Yeah sure, you can also stack classes, or do #table1 , #table2 {stuff here for both id's to be the same} . But in my opinion , using classes is best practice.

Comment: I disagree with that. Id's are always faster than classes, therefor it would be better (in this case, IMO), to stick to the id's

Comment: you're right about that id's are faster, so +1 for that.

Comment: Class-based method is much more reusable - and implements the true power of CSS - that it cascades. Create a base class that has attributes that are always the same, then use a modifier class or an ID to modify and extend (such as your background colours).

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely use classes to achieve what you want. The following uses [BEM](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/):

```
.Table {
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:80%;
    height:98px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.Table--primary {
    background-color: white;
}

.Table--secondary {
    background-color: mintcream;
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<table class="Table">...</table>

<table class="Table Table--primary">...</table>

<table class="Table Table--secondary">...</table>
```